# How to interpret following regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex but i am not able to interpret it: `\w\1`.

I thought it would match : `aa` since it had word `a` twice and first group would be a word for this regex. But its not behaving in this manner.

Does back referencing work only if we place parentheses around regex ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `\w\1`? That's the whole regex? Are you sure this is Java?

Comment: Yes this is a very simple regex in JAVA. I am new to these regex.

Comment: (\w)\1 Captures the matched subexpression and assigns it a zero-based ordinal number.

Comment: I think in Java you need more slashes.

Comment: @d'alar'cop: Yes and no. The regex itself is okay as it is. But in Java, you construct a regex from a string, and literal strings need extra escapes for backslashes. If you were getting the regexp string from anywhere that is not a literal (from stdin, from DB...), you wouldn't write extra slashies. (That said, the regex doesn't work as intended, because as OP noticed, nothing is captured unless there's braces.)

Comment: @d'alar'cop I am not asking for the implementation of the regex. I just want to know taht does the expression mean. What does it represent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\n` refers to the `n`th [*capturing group*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg). However, there are no capturing groups in your regex to refer to. You likely want:

```
(\w)\1
```

<kbd>[demo](http://rubular.com/r/2Uxxs6LEJm)</kbd>

As a Java string that would be `"(\\w)\\1"`.

Comment: So you mean to say that capturing groups need to be enclosed in "braces"?

Comment: @Amber Yes, that's correct. Capturing group 0 always stands for the entire expression.

Comment: @Amber They are called parentheses not braces, braces serve a different purpose in regular expressions.

Comment: @Amber You are welcome, if this answer solves your problem then please accept it to show credit to the answerer.

Comment: @Sniffer I was just waiting for stackoverflow to allow me to accept the answer. (10 min) :)

Comment: @Amber OK great, sorry for that :)

Answer (score 1):

`(\w)\1` Captures the matched subexpression and assigns it a zero-based ordinal number.